How to disable the iOS “Scan Text” feature from TextField in Flutter?
On iOS devices with iOS 15+, the new "Scan Text" button appears in the TextField, context menu.
Do you know how I can disable this feature?

https://i.sstatic.net/XWVe1xGc.png

Have tried to add textInputAction: TextInputAction.none, enableSuggestions: false and autocorrect: false to your textfield?

yes, it doen't help

There are two ways you may could fix your TextField issue. One is this
TextField(enableInteractiveSelection: false,
// Other properties...)
// Optionally, make it read-only if you don't want any input
readOnly: true,

which will prevent users from selecting or copying text, meaning they will not have paste capabilities either.
As I know, there isn't a specific setting in Flutter or an iOS native API that explicitly disables the "Scan Text" feature in a TextField. So the second way you could try is creating a custom TextField and use platform channels to call native iOS code that disables the "Scan Text" feature.
First, create the platform channel in your Flutter app:
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  static const platform = MethodChannel('com.example.disableScanText');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoTextField(
      onTap: () async {
        try {
          await platform.invokeMethod('disableScanText');
        } on PlatformException catch (e) {
          print("Failed to disable scan text: '${e.message}'.");
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

Next, implement the native iOS code in your iOS project:
1.Create a Swift File: In your iOS project, create a new Swift file (e.g., DisableScanText.swift).
2.Implement the Method: Add the following code to disable the "Scan Text" feature:
import Flutter
import UIKit

public class SwiftDisableScanTextPlugin: NSObject, FlutterPlugin {
  public static func register(with registrar: FlutterPluginRegistrar) {
    let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "com.example.disableScanText", binaryMessenger: registrar.messenger())
    let instance = SwiftDisableScanTextPlugin()
    registrar.addMethodCallDelegate(instance, channel: channel)
  }

  public func handle(_ call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) {
    if call.method == "disableScanText" {
      if let textField = call.arguments as? UITextField {
        textField.textContentType = .none
      }
      result(nil)
    } else {
      result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
    }
  }
}

3.Register the Plugin: Register the plugin in your AppDelegate:
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    SwiftDisableScanTextPlugin.register(with: self.registrar(forPlugin: "SwiftDisableScanTextPlugin")!)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}

This setup should help you achieve the desired functionality of disabling the "Scan Text" feature on iOS. However, It requires a good understanding of both Flutter and native iOS development. Also Maintaining platform-specific code can be cumbersome, especially if you need to ensure compatibility with future iOS versions or Flutter updates. Consider The effectiveness of using textContentType to disable "Scan Text" isn't guaranteed, as it may not cover all scenarios where the feature appears. At last, you may have to predict what use cases you're going to face in future before you start adding the native code a custom plugin which may be overkill for many other use cases.

It looks like a workaround solution, but that's okay if it's the best we have
